# Matching using if and then statement

Tags: bash, variables, comparison

I have a script that assign a list of names to a variable

```
$a = tom jerry albert yoyo etc
```

I need to check if the content of another variable within my script matches one of the names assigned to this variable. How can I do this?  My other variable name is `$name`. So my logic should be.

```
if  $name contains in $a
   echo  it matches
esle
    echo it does not match 
fi
```

So is my `$name` is equal to tom then I like to `echo` **"it matches"**

Can you please advice?

Thanks

Comment: This is syntactically invalid shell script, please post actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you would want to use an array to store the names and iterate over it to test for a match:

```
#!/bin/bash

contains()
{
    local element
    for element in "${@:2}"; do
        [ "${element}" = "$1" ] && return 0
    done
    return 1
}

a=(tom jerry albert yoyo)

for name in tom to foo; do
    if contains "${name}" "${a[@]}"; then
        echo "${name} matches"
    else
        echo "${name} doesn't match"
    fi
done
```

---

```
$ ./t.sh
tom matches
to doesn't match
foo doesn't match
```

---

You could even pass by "reference" by using variable indirection, that way you only have to pass the name of the array to `contains` which you want to match against:

```
contains()
{
    local element
    for element in "${!1}"; do
        [ "${element}" = "$2" ] && return 0
    done
    return 1
}

names=(tom jerry albert yoyo)

for name in tom to foo; do
    if contains "names" "${name}"; then
        echo "${name} matches"
    else
        echo "${name} doesn't match"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over the $list variable and check for matches, as in the following excerpt:

```
list="tom jerry albert yoyo etc"

name=tom

for item in $list
do
        if [[ "$item" == "$name" ]]
        then
                echo it matches
        else
                echo it does not match 
        fi
done
```

Comment: I tried this and it doers not work thanks for ur help

Comment: try it and u shall find using bash ..did not work for me and u really do not need a for statement I posted the answer

Answer (score 0):

For a completely portable solution, you could use `case`. Something like

```
case " $list " in
    *" $name "* ) echo "'$name' included in '$list'" ;;
    * ) echo not. ;;
esac
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok I found the answer

```
if [[ "$a" =~ "$name" ]] && [ -n "$name" ]; then
   echo it matches
else
echo it does not match
fi
```

Cheers

Comment: This will incorrectly match `alb`, `to` and any substring that `$a` contains. The "correct" way would be to use an array.

Comment: This will match incorrectly; e.g. with a=xy and name=x.